# How to remote log on mac, but not show my action to other users

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vnc

I want to log remotely from my computer to box with Mac, when I do it with build in Mac's VNC server, user that sits by this mac can see my action. I do not want them to see it (like in windows when I take control other users can see logon screen). Is there a possibility to configure it this way ?

I want to access from Windows.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, regular file sharing or SSH might be a (poor) substitute.

Comment: I want to remotelly control computer (like in Windows RemoteDesktop)

Answer (score 3):

Could try LogMeIn, has Mac options and lets you black-out the users screen while you operate their PC...

Comment: I tried logMeIn but where can I black out user screen ? I can not find this option

Comment: there should be an icon in the options taskbar with an image of a computer screen. definitely offers the option, I use it regularly...

Comment: Do you use it on mac or on windows because I look at logmein forum and it seems that there is no such an option for mac :( .

Comment: I use it on Win7 but have a client I help who runs it on a Mac & he certainly thinks it has the option. He definitely thinks he uses it regularly...

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) product will allow you to lock the screen from prying eyes while you are working remotely.

Comment: Thank you but I want to access from Windows and I'm searching for some free solution.

Comment: Doesn't Windows Remote Desktop use the VNC protocol? That should work unless hiding the screen isn't part of the standard protocol.

Comment: @Darqer Requirements such as this should be in the question.